# Getting an Excel file with many sheets into R

Tags: r, dataset, excel

I am importing data from an Excel file that contains 15 sheets. Each sheets represent a year in which there are observations on the same variables.

Here is what I would like to do (elgantly) from R: import all the data from all the sheets into one dataframe with one new variable which is the sheet where it came from or the year.

I could do all the necessary preparation by hand in Excel and then use read.xlsx("...myfile.xls", 1) but the main aim of my project is to improve my R skills.

Comment: Doing a better search I realise more people have asked very similar questions on stackexchange.com. Apologies.

Comment: I see - this post doesn't belong in stats.stackexchange.com since it focues on "programming, debugging". Is there another place where it would belong better? Data Science?

Comment: Questions on "how do I do X using R" are best asked at [StackOverflow, using the R tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). I tried recommending your question for migration, but this apparently did not work out. I assume our mods judged that your question would have been closed there soon, as well, since there is no reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) package, which allows you to loop over all sheets in a workbook and read them in order. Look at the ["XLConnect for the Impatient" vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnectImpatient.pdf) to check quickly whether this addresses your needs.